# firebase - restrict user from logging in for 14 days

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, mobile-application

I have an admin panel in my app and I want that if a user has been restricted from the admin panel, he/she must not be able to log into the account for 14 days. I am using firebase with react native

Answer (score 2):

You could store the user id in your database (Firestore or Realtime), with a value such as `isBlocked` along with a date that the block was imposed, `dateBlocked`.

Then, when you want to block a user, you simply update the database with these values. When a user logs in, query your DB to see if the user `isBlocked` and that the `dateBlocked` is less than 14 days ago, and you can then decide what to do with your user.